# Validate if object has string

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have this array

```
switched = {"Restaurant":1,"Hotel":2,"Beauty shop":3,"Physiotherapist":4,"Dentist":5,"Bar":6,"Coffee shop":7}
```

and this object

```
result = [{"Google Place URL":"http://www.restaurant.com","Business Type":"Restaurant"},{"Google Place URL":"http://www.hotel.com","Business Type":"Hotel"}]
```

I want to validate if every item of the `result` contains words of `switched`

also, I'm already working with a `for` that returns each item separately

```
item[csvBusinessType] = Restaurant
```

how can I validate if `item[csvBusinessType]` is included in `switched`?

I have tried with

```
let n = switched.includes(item[csvBusinessType]);
```

but I get `Uncaught TypeError: switched.includes is not a function`

Comment: how can I validate if item[csvBusinessType] is included in switched?

Comment: `switched` is an object. `.includes` a method of `Array`

Comment: eh i guess they just wanna see if each key in `switch` matches with corresponding `result` index

Comment: @TheBombSquad Maybe, but we're not here for guesses. And now with the edit the question makes way more sense

Comment: [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) + [Working With Objects | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

There is not good native method for this. Better to use lodash library https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash

Here is an example

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
console.log( _.includes(switched, item[csvBusinessType]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted the object to string and used includes, I don't know if it will be the best way, but I think it is the most supported by browsers

```
      let businessListArray = JSON.stringify(switched);
      let checkBusiness = businessListArray.includes(item[csvBusinessType]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to validate if every item of the result contains words of switched

If you want to validate that *every* item of the result object array contains words of the switched array, you should look into JS Array methods and working with Objects, just as @Andreas suggested.

In this specific case, your `switched` object has keys that appear to match the csvBusinessType of your `item` objects. This is helpful as we can use `Object.keys()` to grab all the keys of your `switched` object as an array of strings.

```
const businessTypes = Object.keys(switched) // = ["Restaurant","Hotel","Beauty shop","Physiotherapist","Dentist","Bar","Coffee shop"]
```

Now that we have grabbed the keys that you want to check against, we can use the [JS Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) `every()` to perform a test against every object in your `result` object array. In this case, we will be testing that the obect's `Business Type` is included in our newly created `businessTypes` array.

```
const resultsValid = result.every((resultObject) => businessTypes.includes(resultObject["Business Type"]));
```

resultsValid is a boolean that is true if all objects in `result` had a Business type that matched one of the keys of your `switched` object.

NOTE: You may want to check Letter Casing before some of these comparisons unless you want to explicitly match only exact matches ("Beauty shop" will NOT match "Beauty Shop" for example).